# Django Rest Framework , How does Modelserializer validate the user input?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a method in ArticleSerializer that check if the length of *title* property. The *title* property is associated with the model (Article).

How does the **validate_title** function execute itself when calling ArticleSerializer class ?

How does the **validate_title** function take value from *title* property ?

```
#necessary module imports
from .models import Article


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ("id",)

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """ check that title is at least 30 chars long
        """
        if len(value) < 30:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("type less")
        return value
```

I am learning Django rest framwork in Udemy

Github link :   https://github.com/pymike00/The-Complete-Guide-To-DRF-and-VueJS/blob/master/03-DRF-LEVEL-ONE/newsapi/news/api/serializers.py

Comment: Calling `is_valid()` on the serializer is what makes the validation runs

Answer (score 2):

Just override the validate method that of the `serializers.ModelSerializer`.

```
#necessary module imports
from .models import Article


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ("id",)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """ check that title is at least 30 chars long"""
        title = attrs.get('title', None)

        if len(title) < 30:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("type less")
        return attrs
```

Ensure you return `attrs`.